# UIAlertController button delegates don't fire (in Modally Segue)

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm using a very basic UIAlertController setup with two buttons.

```
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Leave player?",
        message: "You will not be able to return to this routine after!",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)


    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        println("here")
    }
    let deleteAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Leave", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        println("here")
    }

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(deleteAction)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code is working on the same View with a push segue from a different part of the program. Where the structure is:

```
(MainView) -push> (View1) -push> (View2) -push> (ThisView)
```

Now the AlertController popups and the button return the simple text output.

But in the following situation the AlertController popups but clicking button returns nothing, my breakpoint never fires or just checking the console for the text output returns nothing.

```
(MainView) -modal> (ThisView)
```

Of Course I tried setting the segue in the second situation to a push segue, but it didn't change anything.
So to make no mistake, the AlertController does popup, but the buttons don't respond at all. Can I make a alternative delegate?

Now it just costed me a full day of getting something simple to work. I've tried most tricks like delays or a async block.

Now I'm kind of out of things to try. So please someone enlighten me what I'm doing wrong :)

**UPDATE**

Embedding the MainView in a navigation controller **and** changing the segue to a Push segue, makes the button presses respond..
Adding a navigation controller to fix this is something I could consider, but I would like to keep the Modal segue for its animation. 
Any Ideas?

**Temporary solution**

For now I'll use the push segue and the navigation controller to solve this behaviour. It is not optimal, ,since this view should behave as a popup and not a push like segue, but it works.

Comment: Could you specify where the code is declared? In the MainView or in ThisView?

Comment: Can you post some more code/storyboard to give us a better understanding of what's going on when this alert is being shown?

Comment: The code is declared on ThisView, which is just 1 segue away from the mainView.
ThisView can also be reached from a different part of the program, which has a x amount of push segues in between. 

On ThisView, there is also a timer ticking every second, but I disabled that and most things happening there so it should not do anything.

Also I runned the Alert from different parts of the program, viewdidload, viewdidappear and in one of the loops (which are disabled when the timer if disabled, might you ask to disable that)

So my thought has todo with the modal segue construction..

Comment: are you dismissing `modal` view controller when you presenting alert?

Comment: No, but that would be the function when pressing the leave button. But those buttons does not get registered on top of the modal View. When I change it to a push (segue) and connect it to a navigation controller, the button do respond..

Comment: Weird, because the only possible way I can think of when you'll get such behaviour if `UIAlertController` is deallocated. That means that `self` view controller in `self.presentViewController` should be deallocated as well. But you are saying that you don't dismissing it...

Comment: Use the debugger to list current controller hierarchy.

Comment: have you tried setting the [`ModalPresentationStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle)?

Comment: when you are presenting alert controller?
I believe its because of Model Presentation of view controller

Comment: Can you upload a sample project?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell much from the code you have listed, but I have come across similar issues before, and the cause was that something was deallocating before I expected it to, and thus never received its message.

The best solution I've found is to enable NSZombies.  Xcode will tell you when your action message is getting sent to a deallocated instance. See this answer for how to enable (use the Xcode 4.1 or greater approach):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5387006/2194039

If you don't want to use NSZombies, try putting this into each of your VCs, or other relevant classes:

```
deinit {
    println("This instance is deallocating")
}
```

I know it's just a general idea and nothing concrete, but this has helped me before.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it did not help me. For the moment I leave the whole functionality aside, until there is a solution without having to use push segues.

Comment: I will not downvote, because the thinking is good, but once a controller is presented or pushed, it is held strongly (retain) by the system, so it would not release the alert controller or the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the action in a separate function , and call that function

like this

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Leave player?", message: "You will not be able to return to this routine after!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {(alert : UIAlertAction!) in self.AlertContinue()}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Leave", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(alert : UIAlertAction!) in self.AlertLeave()}))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and then define the methods like this

```
func AlertContinue() {println("here")}
func AlertLeave() {println("here")}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the behaviour did not change. It is like the click events are not getting registered at all..

Comment: one more thing that comes to mind , from the story board , pick (ThisView) and go to attribute inspector , and check if Presentation is set to full screen . also , check (MainView) attributes , for the (Defines Context) checkmark , uncheck it and try

Comment: Both are set like you say. I updated my problem description with a possible fix, but it is not what I would like to use if possible :)

Comment: If the handler blocks are not called, how exactly will this help? Posting for posting sake does not help.